# how to add dynamic null fields as column in sql server

Tags: sql, pivot, union

I have a query with dynamic pivot columns,
I need to union it to have my `grandtotal` at the bottom part,
the problem is  the number of column on the bottom part to be union is not equal with the number of columns with the pivot columns. how can i add columns to my grandtotal column to be union on the pivot column so that they can be union?

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[davehot]
         (
         @article as varchar(10)
        )
        as
        begin
        DECLARE @sizenameS NVARCHAR (MAX)
       SELECT @sizenameS = COALESCE(@sizenameS + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(SizeName)
       FROM
        (   select DISTINCT SIZESET.SizeSetID, SizeName
    from SIZESET
    left join SHIPMENTSIZESET ON SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
    left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
    left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
    left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where ArticleNo =  @article
)src2
ORDER BY SizeSetID


DECLARE @DownDownDown NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @DownDownDown = COALESCE(@DownDownDown + 'ISNULL([' + CAST (SizeName AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(SizeName AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
    FROM
    (   select DISTINCT SIZESET.SizeSetID, SizeName
        from SIZESET
        left join SHIPMENTSIZESET ON SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
        left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
        left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
        left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where ArticleNo = @article
    )src3
    ORDER BY SizeSetID
SET @DownDownDown = LEFT (@DownDownDown, LEN (@DownDownDown)-1)



DECLARE @ToTheLeft NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ToTheLeft = COALESCE(@ToTheLeft + ',SUM([' + CAST(SizeName AS VARCHAR)+'])', 'SUM([' + CAST(SizeName AS VARCHAR)+'])')
    FROM
    (   select DISTINCT SIZESET.SizeSetID, SizeName
        from SIZESET
        left join SHIPMENTSIZESET ON SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
        left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
        left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
        left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where ArticleNo =  @article
    )src
    ORDER BY SizeSetID


    Declare @price nvarchar(max)
select @price = COALESCE(@price + ',' +''''+ CAST(Price AS VARCHAR)+'''', '''' + CAST(Price AS VARCHAR)+'''')
    FROM
    (   select price from pricesizeset 
    join article on ARTICLE.ControlNo = PRICESIZESET.ControlNo 
    where ARTICLE.ArticleNo =  @article
    )price

DECLARE @TOTPRICE nvarchar(max)
declare @grandtotal nvarchar(max)
    select @grandtotal = coalesce(@grandtotal + ', ', cast(sum(total) as nvarchar)) 
        from(
            select (price*quantity) as total
            from
            (
                SELECT distinct(SIZESET.SizeSetID),price, sum(quantity) as [quantity]

                FROM SIZESET LEFT JOIN PRICESIZESET ON PRICESIZESET.SizeSetID = SIZESET.SizeSetID 
                JOIN ARTICLE ON ARTICLE.ControlNo = PRICESIZESET.ControlNo JOIN DESIGN ON DESIGN.DesignID = ARTICLE.DesignID 
                JOIN SHIPMENTSIZESET ON SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID 
                WHERE ARTICLE.ArticleNo = 'EZT02'
                GROUP BY SIZESET.SizeSetID, price
            )tab
        )TOTPRICE
        select(@grandtotal)





DECLARE @JerryPogi NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @JerryPogi =    'SELECT *, ('+ @DownDownDown + ') AS [Date Total] INTO #Pansamantala
            FROM
            (
                select DISTINCT ShipmentSched.ShipmentSchedId, CONVERT(varchar(10), StartDate, 110) as [Start Date], CONVERT(varchar(10), EndDate, 110) as [End Date], SizeName, Quantity
                from SIZESET
                left join SHIPMENTSIZESET ON SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
                left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
                left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
                left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where ArticleNo = '''+@article+'''
            ) JerryGwapo
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(Quantity)
                FOR SizeName
                IN('+@sizenameS +')
            ) JerryHot
            ORDER BY [Start Date]

            SELECT  *  FROM #Pansamantala
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '''','''',''Size Total'','+@ToTheLeft +',  isnull(SUM([Date Total]),0)  FROM #Pansamantala
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
            '''', '''','''','+@price+','''' 
            union
            select
            '''','''','''','+@grandtotal +','''' from #pansamantala

            DROP TABLE #Pansamantala'

            exec(@JerryPogi)
end

exec davehot'EZT02'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to count number of entries in @sizenameS and @DownDownDown by setting the integer values to variables. Then, use `REPLICATE(''''',', number)`.

Start by declaring two INT variables:

```
DECLARE @countS INT
DECLARE @countD INT
```

Store the number of records to these variables straight after you create the column definitions:

```
   SELECT @sizenameS = COALESCE(@sizenameS + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(SizeName)
   FROM
   (   select DISTINCT SIZESET.SizeSetID, SizeName
    from SIZESET
    left join SHIPMENTSIZESET ON SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
    left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID =  SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
    left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
    left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where ArticleNo =  @article
   )src2
   ORDER BY SizeSetID
   SET @countS = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Do the same thing for @DownDownDown

And, your final SQL statement will be:

```
SET @JerryPogi =    'SELECT *, ('+ @DownDownDown + ') AS [Date Total] INTO #Pansamantala
            FROM
            (
                select DISTINCT ShipmentSched.ShipmentSchedId, CONVERT(varchar(10), StartDate, 110) as [Start Date], CONVERT(varchar(10), EndDate, 110) as [End Date], SizeName, Quantity
                from SIZESET
                left join SHIPMENTSIZESET ON SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
                left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
                left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
                left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where ArticleNo = '''+@article+'''
            ) JerryGwapo
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(Quantity)
                FOR SizeName
                IN('+@sizenameS +')
            ) JerryHot
            ORDER BY [Start Date]

            SELECT  *  FROM #Pansamantala
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '''','''',''Size Total'','+@ToTheLeft +',  isnull(SUM([Date Total]),0)  FROM #Pansamantala
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
            '''', '''','''','+@price+','''' 
            union
            select
            '''','''',''''' + REPLICATE(',''''',  @countS) + ',' +@grandtotal + ' from #pansamantala'
```

Comment: Please note, that my solution is not 100% accurate. I have provide just a guideline. I can even see, that I have not added the REPLICATE to one of the UNION statements. please finetune it

Comment: Please note that I have updated my answer. The REPLICATE should really have this syntax: `REPLICATE(''''',', number)`

Comment: i did what you have written but still i got this error
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: I recommend you replace  exec(@JerryPogi) with SELECT @JerryPogi and check the query to see if the number of `'',` placeholders matches the number of column

Comment: im sorry i got a syntax error on replicate,
incorrect syntax near  ','

Comment: sorry, it is a single quote hell. Use the query above

Comment: Basically, the resulting query needs to be converted to this: `REPLICATE(',''''',2)`

Comment: SELECT  *  FROM #Pansamantala
      UNION ALL
   SELECT '','','Size Total',SUM([Small]),SUM([Medium]),SUM([Large]),SUM([Extra Large]),  isnull(SUM([Date Total]),0)  FROM #Pansamantala
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
   '', '','','300','400','500','600','' 
   union all  
   select
   '','','',220000, REPLICATE(',''''',4)

i got this on the select@jerrypogi
still the same error
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
im sorry im not familliar with the replicate function.

Comment: im sorry but i think replicate will not help

Comment: OK, try this one. You need to use REPLICATE(',''''',  @countS), which will convert to the required